# По клику на кнопку поменять ее цвет

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 2 кнопки, с 1 кнопки мы создаем 2 кнопку вот так:

```
private static int X = 100;
private static int Y = 100;
System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonDyn
private void buttonDynamic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddButton(X, Y);
    X += 100;
}
private void AddButton(int x, int y)
{
    // создаем контрол
    buttonDyn = new     System.Windows.Forms.Button(); 
    // устанавливаем необходимые свойства
    buttonDyn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);           
    buttonDyn.Name = "button1";
    buttonDyn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    buttonDyn.TabIndex = 0;
    buttonDyn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // button1_Click - функция обработчик события нажатия на кнопку
    buttonDyn.Click += new System.EventHandler(buttonDyn_Click); 
    Controls.Add(buttonDyn); // добавляем на форму
    //вот здесь меняем цвет кнопки
    buttonDyn.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
}
```

При нажатии на 2 кнопку (которую мы создали динамически) кнопка 1 и кнопка 2  должны поменять цвет:

```
private void buttonDyn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonDynamic.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
        buttonDyn.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
    }
```

Но цвет меняется только на первой кнопке. Предполагаю что программа не понимает к какой кнопке это относится. buttonDynamic ведь создается динамически и их может быть много. Тогда как решить эту задачу?

Comment: хранить ссылки на кнопки в `List<Button>`, в обработчике перебирать `List` и присваивать цвет

Comment: @Exodium идея хорошая, но все равно не работает. Хотя если мы меняем текст на кнопке все работает. Думаю дело в 'Controls.Add(buttonDyn)', но даже если мы его ставим перед элементом списка ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто, в обработчиках событий для этого предусмотрен параметр `sender`. `sender` всегда (не считая экзотических реализаций и ошибок) содержит ссылку на объект, который это событие инициировал.

```
private void buttonDyn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //по коду выше это постоянная кнопка
    buttonDynamic.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
    //для динамических меняем
    //buttonDyn.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
    //на
    (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.DarkBlue; 
}
```

---

и верните `buttonDyn` обратно к состоянию локальной переменной, от этого поля ни какой пользы, только путаница.